# Why does calling a method that is an arrow function not work?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying out vuejs, and I have a very simple app:

```
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app', // 1
        data: { // 2
            myLocalProperty: 'Im a local property value' // 3
        },
        methods: {
            buttonClicked() { // 2
                const newText = 'The new value is: ' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 100);
                this.myLocalProperty = newText; // 4
            }
        }
    });
```

This I call buttonClicked from a button, this works just fine. 
However, if I declare buttonClicked() with an arrow function, it doesn't work. Why?

```
            buttonClicked: () => {
                const newText = "The new value is" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                this.myLocalProperty = newText;
            }
```

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own `this` value; the enclosing scope `this` is just probably `undefined`.

Comment: Because in arrow function `this` no more points to the Vue instance, and they have their own context `this`. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is called lexical scoping. Everything else is already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an arrow function `this` will no longer reference the Vue instance. You need to use the `function` keyword here:

```
buttonClicked: function() {
    const newText = "The new value is" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    this.myLocalProperty = newText;
}
```